# Can I program Arduino Uno R4 On STM32 IDE?

Tags: arduino, stm32, arm, programming, ide

The microcontroller of Arduino Uno R4 is Renesas RA4M1 (Arm® Cortex®-M4).
-So can I program Arduino Uno R4 On STM32 IDE?
-Can I use STM32 library for Arduino Uno R4?
Thanks!!!

Comment: you can use the Renasas e2 studio, which is based on Eclipse too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CubeIDE is just an IDE, basically a preconfigured Eclipse. If you use the compilers and libraries for your MCU it should be possible to use any IDE, including CubeIDE, for typing in code for your MCU. But you don't need an IDE for that, any text editor will do, such as Notepad, although you likely don't want to use it.

And no, you can't use libraries of STM32 on Renesas MCU, just like you can't use Renesas libraries on STM32. Different MCUS need different libraries.